# How do I connect a JBoss4 Message Driven Bean to a topic on a remote server?

Tags: jboss, jms, remote-server

I have a JBoss server (Server A) that is publishing messages on a topic.
I have a message driven bean on another server (Server B) that needs to retrieve the messages from Server A.

How do I go about it? I can easily get everything working if the publisher and subscriber are on the same server but I can't find any information about how to do it using a remote server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/HowDoIConfigureAnMDBToTalkToARemoteQueue) describes how to connect an MDB to a remote queue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, however, the link you provided describes EJB2.1 whereas I was looking for EJB3. This link from the same site has the correct instructions: http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/HowDoIConfigureAnEJB3MDBToTalkToARemoteQueue